# How to populate "ArrayYear" in picker view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

//UI TextFields
@IBOutlet weak var ChassisText: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var YearFromText: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var YearToText: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var MakeText: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var ModelText: UITextField!

//Used Variables
var YearFrom:String = "0"
var YearTo:String = "2020"
var ChassisNumber:String = ""
var ArrayYear:[String] = [""]
var ArrayMake = [String]()
var ArrayModel = [String]()
var i:Int = 0
var holdSelect = 0
//UIPickerView
var pickerselection: UIPickerView!

//Boolean Variables
var checkYearFrom: Bool = false
var checkYearTo: Bool = false
var checkMake: Bool = false
var checkModel: Bool = false

//Picker Actions
func DonePicker()
{
    if checkYearFrom {
        YearFromText.text = "\(ArrayYear[holdSelect])"
        YearFrom = "\(ArrayYear[holdSelect])"
        YearFromText.resignFirstResponder()
        checkYearFrom = false
    }
    else if checkYearTo {
        YearToText.text = "\(ArrayYear[holdSelect])"
        YearTo = "\(ArrayYear[holdSelect])"
        YearToText.resignFirstResponder()
        checkYearTo = false
    }
}
func CancelPicker()
{
    YearFromText.resignFirstResponder()
    YearToText.resignFirstResponder()
    ModelText.resignFirstResponder()
    MakeText.resignFirstResponder()
}

//Picker View Functions
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    if checkYearFrom || checkYearTo {
        return ArrayYear[row]
    }
    else
    {
        return ArrayYear[row]
    }
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    if checkYearFrom || checkYearTo {
        return ArrayYear.count
    }
    else
    {
    return ArrayYear.count
    }
}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    holdSelect = row
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

}

I have the whole code above creating the picker view programmatically and also the cancel and done buttonItem.

This line of code is where I create an Year Array:

```
var YearFrom:String = "0"
var YearTo:String = "2020"
var ArrayYear:[String] = [""]
var i:Int = 0
```

On the viewDidLoad this is where the for loop is created for the year:

```
    for var index = 1980; index <= 2016; index++ {
        ArrayYear.insert("\(index)", atIndex: i)
    }

    i = 0

    //Creating Picker Programatically
    pickerselection = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
    pickerselection.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    pickerselection.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerselection.delegate = self
    pickerselection.dataSource = self
```

In the running phase where I test the picker view on the 'YearFromText' the array that I created is not displayed (1980 - 2016).

Is there something wrong with the implementation of the ArrayYear.

I'm new to swift programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the years in an Array then you can simply do this:

```
let years = (1980...2016).map { String($0) }
```